# Cursor.fetch dosen't work in Matlab

Tags: oracle, matlab, cursor, fetch

i use Matlab 2014 on windows 7 64 bit and Oracle 11.2.0, and I connect it to via Odbc. 
When I try to execute query using matlab I got strange things happend. 
In one case in my first fetch I got only 1 row (the same query returns 28000 row's in sql navigator),  and afer this it returns 'No Data'.  Sometimes it returns 'No Data'  from the begining.
Any time after it in order to use again the cursor i have to restart the Matlab,  otherwise it will not work. 
I thought that the problem is with the ODBC connection,  but when i tried to execut the query in Python,  everything worked just fine.

Someone know what to do? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe post the portion of code that doesn't work?

Comment: conn = database(dbName, user, password);
cursor = exec(conn, query);
cursor = fetch(cursor, 50000)
data = cursor.Data

The first fetch returns only one row. 
When I try to make again the fetch it returns no data, the same query returns in sql navigator 28000 rows.

Comment: I have more complicate part of code that does it in a loop,  but i cant copy it because it is in LAN that not connected to the net,  so i copied to my phone a basic code,  that shows the principal of my code.  Thanks again